# Evaluate the summation $\sum_{k=1}^{n}{\frac{1}{2k-1}}$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, algorithms

I need to find this sum $$\sum_{k=1}^{n}{\frac{1}{2k-1}}$$ by manipulating the harmonic series.

I have been given that $$\sum_{k=1}^{n}{\frac{1}{k}} = \ln(n) + C$$ where $C$ is a constant. I have given quite a bit of thought to it but have not been able to arrive at the solution.

Any method to find this summation would really help a lot.

Comment: Write out the sum, compare to the harmonic series to see the relation.

Comment: Not directly related to the problem, but I want to point out that the formula you gave is only asymptotically true. Indeed, the harmonic number $H_n = 1 + (1/2) + \cdots + (1/n)$ has the following asymptotic expansion $$ H_n \sim \log(n) + \gamma + \frac{1}{2n} - \frac{1}{12n^2} + \frac{1}{120n^4} + \cdots. $$

Comment: $C$ is not a constant, unless you mean $\approx$. (The value of $\sum_{k=1}^n\frac1k-\ln(n)$ approaches a constant, called $\gamma$ or gamma, as $n$ increases.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We can write $\displaystyle \sum^{n}_{r=1}\frac{1}{2r-1} = 1+\frac{1}{3}+\frac{1}{5}+....+\frac{1}{2n-1}+\left[\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{4}+\frac{1}{6}+....+\frac{1}{2n}\right]-\left[\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{4}+\frac{1}{6}+....+\frac{1}{2n}\right]$

So $\displaystyle \sum^{n}_{r=1}\frac{1}{2r-1} = \sum^{2n}_{r=1}\frac{1}{r}-\frac{1}{2}\sum^{n}_{r=1}\frac{1}{r}$

Now Using $\displaystyle \sum^{n}_{r=1}\frac{1}{r} = \ln(n)+\bf{Constant.}$

Answer (score 1):

$$\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{1}{2k-1}=\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{1}{2k}+\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{1}{2k(2k-1)}=\frac{H_n}{2}+\log(2)-\sum_{k>n}\frac{1}{2k(2k-1)}$$
hence it follows that your sum behaves like $\frac{1}{2}\log(n)+O(1)$.

Through the above line and the asymptotics for harmonic numbers, we can say even more:

> $$\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{1}{2k-1}=\frac{1}{2}\log(n)+\left(\frac{\gamma}{2}+\log(2)\right)+O\left(\frac{1}{n}\right).$$

Answer (score 0):

One could use the Euler Summation formular:

$$\sum_{a < x \le b} f(x) = \int_{a}^b f(x) dx + \int_{a}^{b}f'(x)\{x\}dx+f(a)\{a\}-f(b)\{b\}  $$ with $$ f(x) = {1\over 2x-1} $$